# Selected value removing required attribute and hiding span Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been working on this piece of code for quite a while and I tried a lot of different variations but nothing seems to work. I have to admit that I haven't worked with Javascript or JQuery that often so maybe I'm just blind to the mistakes I have made.
What I made is form with a lot of fields, where one them is the approved/not approved field. If the user choses the 'unapproved' option I want other fields that were required before to not be required anymore and hide the red star that I made. So the fields look like this:

```html
<tr>
    <td class="Label" align="left">
    Type:
    </td>
    <td class="InputValue" align="left">
      <select class="DropdownBox" onchange="functionreq()" name="Approval" id="Approval"/>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="YES">Approved</option>
        <option value="NO">Unapproved</option>
      </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="Label" align="left">
    Comment:<span id="hideme" style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="InputValue" align="left">
      <input class="InpTxt" name="txtAppName" type="text" id="hide" required/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now I have tried two different things to remove the required attribute and the red star:
My first try looks like this:

```js
<script>
  function functionreq() {
  if ($("#Approval").val() === "NO") {
      var x = document.getElementById("hideme");
      x.style.display = "none";
      $("#hide").removeAttr('required');
  }
</script>
```

And my second looks like this

```js
<script>
  $('#Approval').on('change', function() {
      $("#hideme").hide();
      $("#hide").removeAttr('required');
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

So both of these don't work and I was wondering if anybody could help me with this or tell me why these are not working. Thank you!

**Snippet with typos removed**

```js
$('#Approval').on('change', function() {
      $("#hideme").hide();
      $("#hide").removeAttr('required');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td class="Label" align="left">
    Type:
    </td>
    <td class="InputValue" align="left">
      <select class="DropdownBox" name="Approval" id="Approval"/>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="YES">Approved</option>
        <option value="NO">Unapproved</option>
      </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="Label" align="left">
    Comment:<span id="hideme" style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="InputValue" align="left">
      <input class="InpTxt" name="txtAppName" type="text" id="hide" required/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is that the correct html? `#hide` doesn't exist, I think you may mean `#RiskComment`.

Comment: @Joe You are right! I will adjust it

Comment: Both your examples work with the ID corrected, was this not working for you?

Comment: In the second you don't need/want the `(jQuery)` - it's not an IIFE.

Comment: I've converted your supplied code to a snippet (along with removing the `onchange=`) and it shows it working fine.  Please add a [mcve] that *demonstrates* the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reveal the input field when the user selects the "Approved" option:

```js
function functionreq() {
  if ($("#Approval").val() === "NO") {
    $("#hideme").hide();
    $("#hide").removeAttr("required");
  } else if($("#Approval").val() === "YES") {
    $("#hideme").show();
    $("#hide").attr("required", "true");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td class="Label" align="left">
    Type:
  </td>
  <td class="InputValue" align="left">
    <select class="DropdownBox" onchange="functionreq()" name="Approval" id="Approval" />
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="YES">Approved</option>
    <option value="NO">Unapproved</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="Label" align="left">
    Comment:<span id="hideme" style="color: #ff0000;">*</span>
  </td>
  <td class="InputValue" align="left">
    <input class="InpTxt" name="txtAppName" type="text" id="hide" required/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ok this is so weird because this still does not work in my code.. But I see it working here

Comment: This suggests something in your code is causing the problem. Try minifying your code bit by bit, until you get to the point where nothing more can be removed while the problem persists. In short, create a [mre] of your problem.

Comment: It works now! I moved the script to a different location in my code (above the fields that it affected) and now it works! Thank you!